# Automate mouse button click with script or macro

Tags: windows-7, mouse, script, automation, macros

I'm searching for a script or macro program which pushes the 4th or 5th mouse button every 5 seconds.

This script or macro program is for a friend who uses Windows 7 on an Asus notebook. I cannot try this because I use opensuse 11.0. I have googled but haven't found anything.

Comment: There may be a more direct way of automating this. What do those buttons do to the system? It might be easier to automate the effect of what those buttons do rather than the button click itself.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to write a script to do that using [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) or [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml).

Answer (score 1):

Is it for a *website*? Then try the [iMacros for Firefox](http://www.iopus.com/imacros/firefox/) addon.