# I need a program that will do a mouse click on the Firefox browser

Tags: windows, windows-xp, automation, macros, remote-control

I need a program that will do a single mouseclick at a certain place on the Firefox browser. Nothing else. It needs to be executable under Windows-XP  (an .exe, .vbs,  etc.)  The mouse click will always be executed at exactly the same place - if the mouse is elsewhere, the program must move the mouse to that point. (If that's required - I don't care if the mouse actually stays where it was before.)  The Firefox window will already be the active window (if that matters.)  I won't be needing any other automated functionality, just what I've said. (The mouseclick is not for a link on a webpage, or an element on a page, it is on the browser.)

How can I do this?

For Windows XP SP3.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automate mouse button click with script or macro](http://superuser.com/questions/180571/automate-mouse-button-click-with-script-or-macro) also see [how to create hotkey for doubleclick?](http://superuser.com/questions/440179/how-to-create-hotkey-for-doubleclick/)

Answer (score 2):

http://www.autohotkey.com/

You can write a short autohotkey script to do the click, then create a shortcut or whatever to start autohotkey and run the script.