# Tool for sending mouse movement/click signals to a browser tab periodically

Tags: mouse, firefox-extensions, userscripts

I'm running a flash application in the browser. The problem is, the application halts if there is no mouse action in 5 minutes. I need an extension or userscript which periodically sends mouse movement or click signals to the application, such that the application will think that I'm still using it.

The application must not interrupt me by doing something with the real screen mouse pointer. All job must be done silently and automatically.

Can you please suggest a tool for this purpose?

(Browser: Firefox 26.0)

Comment: possible duplicate of [I need a program that will do a mouse click on the Firefox browser](http://superuser.com/questions/555447/i-need-a-program-that-will-do-a-mouse-click-on-the-firefox-browser)

Comment: What is your Operating System?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well this is a way much more powerfull tool but if you want you could use [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) and the [flash-selenium](https://code.google.com/p/flash-selenium/) plugin for Selenium and then program as many clicks as you want with the logic you desire and so on.

Otherwise [Adobe Genie](http://sourceforge.net/adobe/genie/wiki/Home/) could be an option

Answer (score 0):

For Windows PCs, I would suggest using [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), you can easily program in mouse movements & actions. You can also compile scripts to executables if you want to distribute to other PC's without AHK installed.